# Easiest method for removing html/xml <tags> from single-line output

Tags: html, xml, sed

I have output from grep I'm trying to clean up that looks like:

```
<words>Http://www.path.com/words</words>
```

I've tried using...

```
sed 's/<.*>//'
```

...to remove the tags, but that just destroys the entire line.  I'm not sure why that's happening, since every '<' is closed with a '>' before it gets to the content.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Grep is greedy by default, meaning it will take everything between the first `<` and the last `>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this for your sed expression:

```
sed 's/<.*>\(.*\)<\/.*>/\1/'
```

**Quick breakdown of the expression:**

```
<.*>   - Match the first tag
\(.*\) - Match and save the text between the tags   
<\/.*> - Match the end tag making sure to escape the / character  
\1     - Output the result of the first saved match 
       -   (the text that is matched between \( and \))
```

---

***More about back-references***

A question came up in the comments that should probably be addressed for completeness.

The `\(` and `\)` are Sed's back-reference markers. They save a portion of the matched expression for use later.

For example, if we have an input string:

> This has (parens) in it. In addition we can use parenslike thisparens
>   using back-references.

We develop an expression:

```
sed s/.*(\(.*\)).*\1\\(.*\)\1.*/\1 \2/
```

Which gives us:

```
parens like this
```

*How the heck did that work?* Let's break down the expression to find out.

**Expression breakdown:**

```
sed s/ - This is the opening tag to a sed expression.
.*     - Match any character to start (as well as nothing).
(      - Match a literal left parenthesis character.
\(.*\) - Match any character and save as a back-reference. In this case it will match anything between the first open and last close parenthesis in the expression.
)      - Match a literal right parenthesis character.
.*     - Same as above.
\1     - Match the first saved back-reference. In the case of our sample this is filled in with `parens`
\(.*\) - Same as above.
\1     - Same as above.
/      - End of the match expression. Signals transition to the output expression.
\1 \2  - Print our two back-references.
/      - End of output expression.
```

As we can see, the back-reference taken from between the parenthesis (`(` and `)`) was substituted back into the matching expression to be able to match the string `parens`.

Comment: Okay, that worked beautifully.  I can't really understand what it's doing, though.  I see it's escaping some characters, but could someone explain a little bit of what's happening (particularly the parens and numeral 1)?

Many thanks!

Comment: @user115360 I added an expression breakdown. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I like the addition of the explanation.

Comment: You've more than answered it.  Thanks!

Comment: With this part, `\(.*\)`, you make the comment that it saves the text. When you save, what that mean in practice? I was thinking that might be a grouping. But then I realized you were escaping both. So what exactly is that doing?

Comment: @JaredFarrish It is regex grouping. Sed uses `\(` and `\)` as the grouping characters instead of `(` and `)`. That way if you wanted to match an expression with parens in it, you don't need to escape them. Also, any matched group in sed can be used in subsequent portions of the expression.

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't aware of that. I still haven't quite gotten the hang of grouping and back references. I'm pretty sure that I need groups to get [this side learning project I'm working on to work](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ubuEU/1/), but I just haven't gotten the hang of it yet.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I added a back-reference example hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I appreciate you putting in the effort to add so much description to your answer. I did a little light editing to address some simple formatting issues I saw. Hope you don't mind.