# Custom XML Tags with Doxygen

Tags: windows, doxygen

In reference to this solution:
[Custom tags with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537043/custom-tags-with-doxygen)

It seems this does not work if I use XML (c#) style for documenting.
I tried to add a "change" tag:

`ALIASES = "change=\xrefitem change \"Change\" \"Changes\""`

However, when I use it in my documentation:

```
<change>Bojan Hrnkas, 14.08.2012: Optimized performance.</change>
```

The HTML Output looks like this:

`<change>Bojan Hrnkas, 14.08.2012: Optimized performance.</change>`

Is there a way to implement aliases for xml tags?

Comment: +1 Nice question. This would be a really nice feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) configuration file option to replace custom XML commands with an alias. For example, defining

```
ALIASES = "change=\xrefitem change \"Change\" \"Changes\""
```

we could use `INPUT_FILTER` to find and replace

```
<change>Text</change>
```

with

```
\change Text
```

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10988993/623518) one could use sed to perform this transformation using something along the lines of

```
sed 's/<change>\(.*\)<\/change>/\1/'
```

Comment: I assume 'sed' is the linux "Stream EDitor". That sounds like a possible solution. However, my development environment is Visual Studio on Windows, so 'sed' is not an option. Visual Studio is the reason I insist on using xml-style comments.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then you should add the Windows tag to your question. Anyway, [sed is avaiable for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127318/623518). Alternatively, you could [use Powershell to achieve the same result](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6028937/623518).

Comment: @BojanHrnkas Install a sed from GNUWin32, MinGW or Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm that custom tags are not supported when using XML-Style documentation. My solution was to mix two styles, so now I have <summary> along with @change{}. Not very nice, but it works.